# Changing the contents of a JComboBox during runtime

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jcombobox

Alright so I'm trying to create a combo box that will update it's contents during runtime except I have no clue how to do this without receiving a bunch of errors.  Is there some sort of method that I can use in order to accomplish this?  For example, I have a vector that might start out with the name in drawers 1 and 2 be hi and bye.  Then during runtime the program will change drawer one and two to eggs, sausage and add a third drawer with the name being computer.  How can I go about changing the name on a JComboBox during runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to clear the combobox of all entries using removeAllItems(), then re-add the items from the Vector using addItem().

Answer (score 0):

The data shown in the ComboBox actually lives in its *model* - some subclass of `ComboBoxModel`.

`DefaultComboBoxModel` has methods for adding and removing elements.  If you want to completely replace the combo box's contents at runtime, the simplest way might be to just build a new model and call `theComboBox.setModel(theNewModel)` with it.  Also see `setSelectedItem()` for setting the selection.